# how to verify if an element exsit or not in an NSMutubleArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I'm new to objective-c.
I have an NSMutableArray . I wrote this:

```
for (int i=0; i<[allCombinations count]; i++)
{
    NSString *date = [[allCombinations objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"keydate"];
    NSString *cachdepeDate = [date substringToIndex:8];
}
```

How can i see if cachdepeDate is alrady exsit in my NSMutbleArray?

If it is not exist how do I add it?

Should I make for loop, or there is a method for this?

Can i sort the NSMutbleArray?

Dates are in this format: "20110531" "YYYYMMDD". 
Thank you!

Comment: What is `cachdepeDate`? Your code is incomplete.

Comment: @KennyTM  sorry , cachdepeDate=[date substringToIndex:8];, it's a tring like this "20110531"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following

```
[yourArray containsObject:cachdepeDate];
```

Comment: if([deparatureDates containsObject:cachdepeDate]==0) ? but if the object is at indice 0 it will return 0 ?

Comment: it just returns YES or NO. You would write if (![yourArray containsObject:cachdepeDate]) [yourArray addObject:cachdepeDate];

Comment: if my array don't contain, so if ([yourArray containsObject:cachdepeDate]==NO) [yourArray addObject:cachdepeDate]; ?

Answer (score 0):

NSArray already has the [`containsObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject%3a) method. But even if it didn't, this would be simple to write:

```
for (id object in array) {
    if ([object isEqual:cachdepeDate]) {
        // it's in there
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, would you care to explain in what way my answer was inaccurate? Merely downvoting is useless and rude, because it does nothing to correct any misinformation given.